# Combobox filed in Extjs (6.x.x) sometimes it works fine and sometimes no

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, extjs5

I´ve a following combobox in extjs:

```
                    xtype: 'mcomboboxfield',
                    itemId: 'component1-'+i+'-mes-'+mesSeleccionado,
                    cls: 'component1-cls',
                    fieldLabel: 'PATRON',
                    height: 333,
                    flex: 4,
                    displayField: 'nombre',
                    valueField: 'codPatron',
                    editable: false,
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    shadow : false,
                    left:0,
                    valueOriginal: codPatron,
                    value: codPatron ,
                    store : 'sPatronesTodos',
                    disabled: isWeekDisabled,
                    layout:{
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function(cmp) {
                            cmp.getStore().load();
                        },
                    }
```

Sometimes works fine, but sometimes `codPatron` is showed instead `nombre`. Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The value is shown when there is no corresponding entry in the backing store. To fix it, make sure there is an entry for every value in the backing store.